# Add updated tag and change accepted answer or keep aging question as is

Tags: discussion

I asked a question in 2013 and it was answered sub-optimally with the best workaround available at the time so I accepted that answer. The question recently had a bounty offered on it and someone answered with a great, simple up to date answer that answers my question perfectly BUT I originally tagged the question with a software version and the new answer doesn't apply to the tagged software version. (The new answer doesn't work in the version the question is tagged with.)

***I can do one of two things but which is right***

- accept the new answer and add a tag for the newer version (more helpful to SuperUser community)
- upvote the new answer but keep tags and accepted answer (seems more fair since the answer isn't relevant to the question as asked)

I suspect if the poor guy offering a bounty for an updated answer would have asked a new question, some zealot would have marked it duplicate and linked to mine that's out of date.

Comment: “I suspect if the poor guy offering a bounty for an updated answer would have asked a new question, some zealot would have marked it duplicate and linked to mine that's out of date.” - Ridiculous..if the user indicated they were using an entirely different version then you specified, the only way it would be a duplicate, is if solutions were applicable to both versions. Calling dedicated community users, zealots, for closing a question that can easily be reopened is a little toxic

Comment: The accepted answer and both answers that were awarded bounties was applicable to Office 2013 by the way. Used Office 2013 with a strike through button on the ribbon bar for years (Word) but essentially the same.

Comment: @Ramhound My question was originally tagged with Office 2010 and the individual ribbon button wasn't available in that version to my knowledge. The only way to get it was add a whole toolbar.

Comment: @Ramhound I really just wish it'd get converted to a community question because I don't have time (or office licenses) to correctly test the answers and mark the best one.

Comment: Stack Exchange discontinued the concept of community wiki questions a number of years ago, only community wiki answers exist, and that is entirely up to the author.